# Is it possible to have a strong scout?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Here is a good question: Is it possible to have a scout that can take on a tank-destroyer for power of shell?
[image: scout tank WOT]

Because I have been looking for a scout in all nation areas.

Comment: What do you mean with "can take on a tank-destroyer"?
Penetration?
DPM?
Mobility?
Because with Penetration, there are enough TD's which arent armored (Skorpion for example). DPM? there are enough TD's which don't have a high DPM as compared to many lights. Mobility? okey... its hard to find a Light Tank which is much slower than a TD on its tier.

Answer (score 4):

Your Question seems kinda weird, but I will try to answer it.

1. Is it possible to have a strong scout?

Yes, there are a lot of strong Light Tanks, f.e. the Russian T 100LT or the French EBR 105.

2. Is it possible to have a scout that can take on a tank-destroyer for power of shell?

No, and that's for good reason. Tank Destroyers are meant to have good guns and high damage potential.
Light Tanks are basically the exact opposite of that, they are meant to be stealthy, fast, small. Light Tanks are not made to deal damage in the first place, they are made to scout the enemy Tanks, so that your team can kill them. Wargaming purposely put weak guns on Light Tanks because they don't want them to be overpowered. If Light Tanks had similar guns compared to Tank Destroyers, why even play TD's?

To summarize:

There are a ton of strong Light Tanks in the game, but none have actual TD guns. A Light Tank is strong if it hast good mobility, camo, view range, and a decent LT gun.
Light Tanks are probably the hardest class to play in the game, so if you are new, you should learn the game first by playing easier tanks like Tank Destroyers or Heavy Tanks.
Light Tanks are played to scout the enemy team and farm spotting damage instead of causing damage by yourself. They are mainly to support your team but are very strong if you are a good player, they can deal damage by themselves but not as well as a TD.

Some examples for good Light Tanks:

1. Chinese Type 64 (Premium Tank at tier VI)
2. French EBR 105 (Tech tree Tank at tier X)
3. German HWK 30 (Premium Tank at tier VIII)

Answer (score 1):

WOT has different classes of tanks with different strengths and weaknesses.

See [WOT-Homepage - Vehicle types and functions](https://worldoftanks.com/en/content/guide/general/vehicle_types/)

Tank destroyers(TD) have a heavy hitting and accurate gun and good front armor and a good angle to make projectiles bounce. In their back, they've got weak armor. They're far less agile in terms of turning and driving.

Because of that, a scout can simply drive bedind a TD and shoot in its weak spots on its back. Moreover, with broken tracks most TDs are easy fodder for all other tanks.

Short description:

Heavy:

- Heavy armor
- few weak spots
- good gun
- slow moving/turning

Medium:

- moderate gun
- moderate armor (all sides)
- moderate speed
- depends a lot on the tank itself

Light (Scouts):

- fast and agile
- low or medium gun
- no armor
- pretty good spotting abilities

Tank Destroyers:

- good gun
- good front armor
- weak side and back armor
- slow, not agile

Self Propelled Guns (SPG):

- good gun
- can shoot over obstacles
- bad manueverability
- pretty slow
- no armor

*Take care as each tank has its own properties. You got mobile TDs with no armor, you got immobile heavy TDs, see [T28](https://worldoftanks.com/en/tankopedia/8225-A39_T28/) vs [Hellcat](https://worldoftanks.com/en/tankopedia/11553-A41_M18_Hellcat/).*

Basically, it's a game of rock paper scissors: Heavy > Medium > Light > TD > Heavy with SPGs being a special case.

WOT depends heavily on strategic movements and knowing enemies weak spots. A new player with a T10 Maus(pretty much unkillable) can die to experienced T8 players that know its weak spots.

Feel free to edit my answer and correct it, I didn't play WOT for over 2 years now.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

[image]

Although as others have pointed out there are quite a few potent scouts (that can double as mediums), at the higher tiers, there is one that stands out in the sense of *"power of shell"*. The second gun on the **[T49](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Tank:A100_T49)** can do a whopping **1000 dmg**. It's comparable to the KV-2 at its tier, except it has speed and agility.

> ...when it receives the deadly 152mm gun, the T49 becomes one of the most dangerous enemies you'll face in Tier 9 - 10 ranks, especially if you play lightly armored tanks (such as in the French line). Its deadly gun can deal up to 1000 damage and can do serious module damage to your tank if lands a critical hit.

Note that while the **alpha damage** of this *'derp gun'* is immense, it does have significant drawbacks. Its accuracy, aim and reload time (20s!) are more like artillery than a regular tank, and even its AP rounds have scout levels of penetration (i.e. bad). So you'll need to get to almost contact close range.

However, if you're used to playing autoloader scouts (like the French AMX 13 90 and 13 105), where you sneak around the battlefield and find isolated targets of opportunity, empty a clip then disappear for the reload, you'll be just fine. HE is the way to go, and **make sure you go for soft targets**, or focus on the rear armour (forget about superheavies like the Maus though). This thing goes through lightly armoured German tank destroyers like the Grille 15 like butter.

Bit of **history**: As you can probably tell from the name (*"152 mm Gun-Launcher XM81 (conventional)"*), the gun is an odd duck.

[image]

The T49's real life counterpart that entered service in 1967, the [M551 Sheridan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M551_Sheridan), had a short, stubby, rifled barrel designed to fire both huge shaped charges ([HEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-explosive_anti-tank) rounds) and the [MGM-51 Shillelagh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MGM-51_Shillelagh) guided missile. Either of these would have allowed the otherwise unimpressive light tank to defeat the enemy heavy tanks of its time.